# VBA Enable only worksheet scrolling while UserForm is active

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to enable only the worksheet scrolling while userform is active?

```
.show (vbmodeless)
```

Doesn't work for my needs as it enables all editing in worksheet, but I need to let the end user to only scroll the worksheet.

Could someone please share an answer to my question, please?

Comment: Maybe set a protection to the sheet?

Comment: I tried something like that, but ran into a problem of not being able to unprotect it

Comment: What kind of problem? Unprotecting the sheet shouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: Yeah! Is it the only way?

Comment: That's the idea of protection: to protect the sheet. Why use something else?

Comment: I will look into that. Maybe it also didn't work because I am filling the sheet via userform comboboxes etc and it didn't let me, and to unprotect the sheet before every change event and then protecting it again would be a nightmare to write

Comment: You would protect the sheet when you open the form and unprotect it when the form closes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event). Advantage: User can still copy data from the sheet or look into other open workbooks/sheets, while the accepted answer prevent that because the form is modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you put a vertical scroll bar on the form itself and use changes in the value of the scroll bar to scroll the worksheet using vba code. The form can then be modal and you retain control of the worksheet.

For example, I put a scrollbar on a modal form and ran this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    Debug.Print ScrollBar1.Value
    Sheet1.Rows(ScrollBar1.Value + 1).Select
End Sub
```

Which worked fine. You will need to adjust the settings of the scroll bar to be sensible in relation to the size of the worksheet and the way you want the user to interact, but if scrolling is the only function you want to allow, then perhaps this could work.

Comment: And to avoid using select, you can just use `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ScrollBar1.Value` And remember setting min value to 1 instead of the default 0.

Comment: Thanks @ChristoferWeber that may be a better approach. I fixed the code to avoid the row 0 problem. Using select works quite well visually for the user, if you actually want the user to select a row in the sheet and then hit a button on the form to do something.

Comment: Also adding the same code to `ScrollBar1_Scroll()` makes you able to scroll it in realtime without using the arrows, which is nice.

Comment: Cool - using scroll actually works well when you have the scroll bar min and max value correspond to the actual selectable rows.